# Extending jQuery Validate methods to validate multiple CSV IP addresses

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I am using the http://jqueryvalidation.org/ plugin for client side validation (yes, I will be sure to also server side validate).

I wish to validate a comma separated list of IP addresses.  There are many solutions to validate an IP, and the following happens to be included with the plugin.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("ipv4", function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/i.test(value);
}, "Please enter a valid IP v4 address.");
```

As indicated, however, I wish to validate multiple IPs separated by commas. How can this method be extended to validate 0 or more IP addresses separated by a comma?

Comment: probably the classic way is the better: get the string, split it by ',' and after that iterate your result array for each ip(not the quickest but probably the best)

Comment: Thanks HellBaby.  Should a totally new method be created, or can the string be split and then the original method be called?

Comment: 1st you can try @David Knipe's method and if doesn't work I'll recommend you to create a new method which will validate each ip address in part(cause in your method it will validate all the string content and if the 4th isn't ok but the rest are will return you a error validation message)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it, unless you want to allow an empty list:

```
/^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?),)+$/i.test(value + ',')
```

Comment: Thanks David, What would be required for an empty list?

Comment: You could add `|,` at the end. And then, because `|` has low precedence, you'd have to enclose it in brackets, otherwise the `^` and `$` wouldn't behave as expected. Like this: `/^(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?),)+|,)$/i.test(value + ',')`. Alternatively, deal with the empty-list case separately: `/^(...,)+$/i.test(value + ',') || value == ''`.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('validIP', function(value) {

    if (!value.length)
        return true

    list_ip = value.split(',');

    for(j = 0; j< list_ip.length; j++){
        var split = list_ip[j].split('.');

        if (split.length != 4)
            return false;
        for (var i=0; i<split.length; i++) {
            var s = split[i];
            if (s.length==0 || isNaN(s) || s<0 || s>255)
                return false;
        }

        }, ' Invalid IP Address');
    return true
    }



    Usage:

    jQuery("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            validIP: true
        }
    }
}
```

This returns false, if there is even a single string which is not a proper ip. 
Returns true for null string